# Finding the optimal 3D box sizes for a group of 3D rectangular items

Tags: algorithm, optimization, calculus

When I say box I am talking about shipping boxes.

I have a number of random sized, small items that I need to pack into as few boxes as possible.
I need to know what box sizes are optimal.

- All items are [rectangular prisms](https://www.google.com/search?q=rectangular%20prisms).
- It's easy to exclude a box size for an item which is too large to fit.
- I know the box sizes (they are the available box sizes which I have in-stock)
- Items can be positioned horizontally or vertically, not diagonal.
- As many boxes as required can be used. The goal is to use as few boxes as possible.
- Multiple box sizes may be used to optimally fit the varying-sized items.

What algorithm exists that allows me to calculate the box sizes I need to use for optimal space usage? **To fit the most items into as few boxes as possible.**

The available box sizes come from what I have available, in-stock. You can create a finite number of made up box sizes for example purposes.

Comment: So this involves only 2 dimensions? length and width?

Comment: This sounds similar to `Knapsack` which is `NP-Complete`. You could take a look at algorithms to approximate `Knapsack` and see if you can adapt one to your needs.

Comment: @FrancisP Cubic, Length, width and height. I don't know the *technical* word for a cubic rectangular shape.

Comment: @FrancisP The word is just rectangular prism. I edited it.

Comment: So how did you solve this ? Is their any ready made classes or code in PHP ? Any idea? Writing one myself is going to take days!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a generalization of the [Bin packing problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem), meaning it is NP-Hard.

To see this, imagine all bins and packages have the same width and height, and additionally all bins (but not packages) have the same length.  Then it is a one-dimensional problem:  we have bins of size V, and packages of size a<sub>1</sub>, a<sub>2</sub>, ..., a<sub>n</sub>.  This simplified case is exactly the Bin-packing problem.  Thus, a fast solution to your problem gives us a fast solution to bin-packing, so your problem is at least as hard; and since bin-packing is NP-Hard, so is your problem.

---

There are some approximation algorithms available though; for example, it's easy to show that the simple [first-fit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem#First-fit_algorithm) algorithm *(put every item in the first bin that it fits into)* will never do worse than 2x the optimal solution.

The similar "First Fit Decreasing" algorithm *(sort the items in descending order, then put every item in the first bin it fits into)* is even better, guaranteeing to be within about 25% of the optimal solution.  There is also another, slightly more complicated algorithm called [MFFD](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0885064X85900226) which guarantees to be within about 20%.

And of course, with only 7 boxes, you could always just brute-force the solution.  This will require about 7<sup>n</sup> steps *(where `n` is the number of items)*, so this solution is infeasible with more than a dozen or so items.

Comment: My problem with this is that the bin sizes I will choose from is partially based upon the total volume of the items. Example: Many small items are cheaper to send in a large UPS box than in many small USPS flat rate boxes. i.e. as total volume increases it is *usually* better to use a larger bin.

Comment: @unixman83: -_- The question mentions fitting items into the fewest boxes, it says nothing about value.  I think you will find that your new problem is a generalization of Knapsack, though, so you are still out of luck with finding the optimal solution :\ Try looking up some Knapsack approximations.

Comment: Yeah. Thanks for answering the space fitting problem I was having though. This is definitely a help.

Answer (score 2):

You have described a variation of the [knapsack problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem).  Check out the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem) for more detail about approaches to the problem than could be given here.

Comment: Being a "variation of the knapsack problem" does not make it NP-complete.

Comment: Hey, I didn't say it was NP complete! But you can write entire books on the subject and I didn't want to attempt to sum it up in 100 words or less.

Comment: This answer doesn't deserve a 0 rating. Sure it doesn't answer the question I asked. But it is probably a more complete answer for the problem which I am facing.