# Python | Calculate Volume with Objects of Set Size Internally

Tags: python, volume, logistics

I'm trying to figure out how to calculate how many boxes can fit into a shipping container for my work. Does anyone know how I can do this in with Python? There's an example here:

`http://www.searates.com/reference/stuffing/`

Basically, `user` enters some different dimensions for `boxes`, `quantities` and `weights`. The `program` then would return how full the `container` is or how many more of each `box` could be added to it. It would also calculate `weights` of the entire unit.

Even more ideally, would be a picture describing how it's packed.

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10113717/finding-the-optimal-3d-box-sizes-for-a-group-of-3d-rectangular-items for some ideas.

Comment: Voting to close because either this is a duplicate (of the question linked by @Bo102010) or this question is too general (it's not clear what Python has to do with things… if you know how to program Python: what part of solving the problem don't you understand? If you don't know Python: possibly learning that would be a good start). Please edit your question to make it more specific.